# Discord.js Bot disregards prefix and will respond to anything infront

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've had this bot working for a while now and for some reason, the bot will now respond to any prefix infront of it, rather than the set prefix.

```js
const PREFIX = '$';
bot.on('message', message => {
    let argus = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch (argus[0]) {
        case 'yeet':
            message.channel.send("yeet")
        break;       
    }
});
```

Comment: You never even check for the prefix you just substring its length. Assuming `PREFIX = "!"` then `PREFIX.length = 1` and `"?".length = 1` so both will behave identically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you're not checking if the message begins with your prefix. So, your code is executed for every message, and if the command is after a substring the same length of `PREFIX`, it'll trigger the command.

Corrected code:

```js
// Example prefix.
const PREFIX = '!';

bot.on('message', message => {
  // Ignore the message if it's from a bot or doesn't start with the prefix.
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

  // Take off the prefix and split the message into arguments by any number of spaces.
  const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/g);

  // Switching the case of the command allows case iNsEnSiTiViTy.
  switch(args[0].toLowerCase()) {
    case 'yeet':
      message.channel.send('yeet')
        // Make sure to handle any rejected promises.
        .catch(console.error);

      break;
  }
});
```